# Avoid Page Load on Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a website on asp.net.
In my page I have a calendar where the user can select a date of a performed surgery, connected to a SQL Server Database. I want to show two different messages:

1. In the case of there's a performed surgery on the selected date, it will show a GridView. I want to show a message saying "Surgeries Performed".
2. In case there isn't any surgery performed on that selected day, I want a label saying "Surgeries not performed"

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       GridView1.DataSourceID = "";
       GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
       GridView1.DataBind();
       GridView1.Visible = true;
       SurgeonsLabel.Visible = false;
       NursesLabel.Visible = false;

       if (GridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
       {
           UnscheduledSurgery.Text = "No Surgeries had been performed on the selected date. Please select other date.";
       }
       else
       {
           UnscheduledSurgery.Text = "Surgeries performed on the selected date: ";
       }
   }
   ```

I can't find an event where I can make the code for this work. I can't do it on page load, because it always show something, and neither I can make it work on Calendar_Selected, because the GridView1 isn't updated yet (so at first show the first message).
Which event should I use?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.Visible = true;
    SurgeonsLabel.Visible = false;
    NursesLabel.Visible = false;

    if (GridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        UnscheduledSurgery.Text = "No Surgeries had been performed on the selected date. Please select other date.";
    }
    else
    {
        UnscheduledSurgery.Text = "Surgeries performed on the selected date: ";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work as I want.
I want an event that allow to find the rows right after the Gridview is processed. In the case of a date where there's a surgery, it shows the message that there isn't and the gridview appears. If I click again on the same date, the message changes (because the gridview is already there).
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simplified example that shows how to use a GridView the way you want.  You'll have to adapt it to your exact situation but it illustrates how to display a message when there's no data.  I wrote this code in Visual Studio so it's tested and it works.  Try it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                There is no data.
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShow" Text="Show" OnClick="btnShow_Click" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnHide" Text="Hide" OnClick="btnHide_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The code behind would look like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var data = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            data.Add(1, "John");
            data.Add(2, "Bob");
            GridView1.DataSource = data;  
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```